# ternary operator default value

Tags: c++, ternary-operator, clamp

I am wondering a bit about the `ternary operator` mainly in `C++` but I think it might apply for other languages as well.

The best example of the problem I am having, (or should I call it a problem? Well a conceptual problem I guess.), would be **clamping values**.

```
float clamped = (x<0.3) : 0.3 ? x;
```

I find myself wanting to write this piece of code, however `x` might be complex say we have something like this:

```
float clamped = (1.f - x + my_function()) > .2f ? .2f : (1.f - x + my_function());
```

This is where it's out of hand in my opinion and I would rewrite it:

```
float clamped = (1.f - x + my_function());
if (clamped > .2f)
    clamped = .2f;
```

So this leads up to two questions really

1: Is there a defaulting behavior so I could say "do this if true, else just do what it said", in pseudo-code something like: `float clamped = (1.f - x + my_function()) > .2f : .2f ? **default**;`

2: If I would still do it the first way, will it first evaluate the condition, and if it is `false`, do another evaluation to get the value from `(1.f - x + my_function())`?

Hope some of it makes sense, it's something which I haven't gotten around to understand until now.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the max function for this:

```
float clamped = max(1.f - x + my_function(), .2f);
```

Comment: And the biggest question is.. WHY haven't I done that connection before? Thank you it is of course true. There are however cases where I might want to use it similarly but have a `type a = (blah) : x ? blah;` where `min/max` doesn't solve it, but really still thankful.

Comment: +1 (but the function corresponding to the OP's actual code would be `min`).

Comment: @qrikko Re your generic example: just replace the second `blah` with `true`.  (But that's just for this specific example.)

Comment: @James Wouldn't that be `false`? But I think he meant something along the lines of `type a = (condition(blah)) : x ? blah`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
float v;
float processed = (v = expr) > 0.f ? special_val : v;
```

?

Or more generically

```
type tmp;
type result = condition(tmp = expr) ? special_val : tmp;
```